# Error installing java on Virtual Machine

Tags: ssh, command-line

I am trying to deploy a server app (BaasBox) to Google app  Engine

BaasBox requires java 1.6 or higher to execute.

when I check for java on the virtual machine using `java -version`,
I get this:

```
    The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

The problem comes when I attempt installing the `openjdk-7` listed above, I get this output error:

```
    myname@instance-2:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core java-common
  libasyncns0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2
  libflac8 libfontconfig1 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libpcsclite1 libpulse0 libsndfile1 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisenc2 tzdata-java
Suggested packages:
  default-jre equivs cups-common liblcms2-utils pcscd pulseaudio
  icedtea-7-jre-jamvm libnss-mdns sun-java6-fonts fonts-dejavu-extra
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei
  ttf-indic-fonts-core ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts
  ttf-bengali-fonts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core java-common
  libasyncns0 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcups2
  libflac8 libfontconfig1 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libogg0 libpcsclite1 libpulse0 libsndfile1 libvorbis0a
  libvorbisenc2 openjdk-7-jre-headless tzdata-java
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,107 kB/43.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err http://gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libnss3-ns
sdb all 2:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libnss3-nssdb all 2
:3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main libnss3 amd64 2:3.1
7.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-ns
sdb_3.17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.
17.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-mi
ssing?
```

Comment: Try running `apt-get update`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the ommision of  `apt-get update` was the root of the problem. pls repost your comment as an answer so i could accept it